# ImportError:libpng16.so.16 cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, matplotlib

After installing matplotlib successfully on my Fedora19,I tested my code written by python. 
Unfortunately,I got this ImportError .

```
$ python ren.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ren.py", line 10, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 32, in <module>
    from matplotlib.image import FigureImage

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png

ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have found the file "libpng16.so.16" and copied it to /usr/lib.
But nothing happened.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _how_ did you install matplotlib?

Comment: I downloaded the source code and exec “sudo python setup.py install”.

Comment: did it give you any errors?  It looks like a linking issue.

Comment: In fact not.I have not got errors while installing matplotlib.so I'm confused about this.As I mentioned,I have found the file "libpng16.so.16" and copied it to /usr/lib. But nothing happened.

Comment: are you sure you are running with the version of python you installed matplotlib with?  I am asking these question because you clearly have and install/linking problem, but have not provided enough information to sort out exactly what the problem is.  Also, don't move around stuff your package manager has installed, that can only lead to chaos later.

Comment: and are you sure you have 32bit vs 64bit sorted out correctly?

Comment: I don't know why this error shows.But I tested the code today,the error disappeared.perhaps,I have installed something(maybe gitstats) for other project yesterday which is needed by it exactly.

Comment: thank you for the attention,Thomas :).

Answer (score 6):

Use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng16-16
```

Answer (score 5):

copy libpng16.so.16 to /usr/lib/ may be ok.
in my computer(Fedora 19), libpng16.so.16 can be found in /usr/local/lib

Comment: this works for me, seems like by default matplot looks for libpng in /usr/lib I built libpng from source and it was placed in /usr/local/lib. `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib` solved the problem (I'm on on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Solved the problem on my CentOS machine as well.

Comment: Soft link is enough

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem with you. Maybe you can try copy libpng16.so.16 to /usr/lib64/. It works for me